# Merge two sorted Linked Lists in ascending order in Python: Issue with Singly Linked List pointer update

Tags: python, python-3.x, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
class ListNode:
     def __init__(self, x):
         self.val = x
         self.next = None

a = ListNode(5)
b = ListNode(10)
c = ListNode(20)


e = ListNode(0)
f = ListNode(5)
g = ListNode(21)
h = ListNode(30)


a.next = b
b.next = c

e.next = f
f.next = g
g.next = h
```

So I have two singly linked lists with heads `a` and `e`

I want to merge in ascending order of their values. For now, I want to merge them be iterating through both the linked lists, comparing values UNTIL one of the linked lists reaches `None` (one of the linked lists are shorter than the other and so one will reach `None` before the other)

```
class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1, l2):

        tempNode = ListNode(0)
        returnNode = tempNode

        while (l1.next != None) and (l2.next != None):



            if l1.val < l2.val:

                print("l1.val < l2.val", l1.val, l2.val)
                tempNode.next = l1

                tempNode = tempNode.next
                l1 = l1.next

            elif l1.val == l2.val:

                print("l1.val == l2.val", l1.val, l2.val)

                #If both the values are equal, assign l1's value first
                #then make l2's value follow l1's value using tempNode 

                tempNode.next = l1 
                tempNode = tempNode.next #Because of the previous statement, after execution of this statement, I'm assuming tempNode.val is now l1.val and tempNode.next = l1.next

                #tempNode.next is supposed to be equal to l1.next, instead assign it to l2
                tempNode.next = l2
                tempNode = tempNode.next #Because of the previous statement, after execution of this statement, I'm assuming tempNode.val is now l2.val and tempNode.next = l2.next

                #Increment both l1 and l2
                l1 = l1.next
                l2 = l2.next


            else:
                print("l1.val > l2.val", l1.val, l2.val)
                tempNode.next = l2

                tempNode = tempNode.next
                l2 = l2.next

sol = Solution()
sol.mergeTwoLists(a, e)
```

So here's what I would ideally like to happen but clearly is NOT happening as you will see when you print the statments!

`l1.val = 5 > l2.val = 0`

increment or move forward with l2!

`l1.val = 5` which is `==` `l2.val == 5`

they are both equal, so move `l1` to it's next AND `l2` to it's next

Now, `l1.val` should be `10` and `l2.val` should be `21`, but
`l1.val` is being printed as `5` and `l2.val` is being printed as `21` and stuck in some infinite loop..

Why does `l1.val` stay at `5` instead of being updated to `10` and why does it stay in this infinite loop instead of one of them reaching their ends according to my `while` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is in the following code fragment

```
tempNode.next = l1 
tempNode = tempNode.next 
tempNode.next = l2
tempNode = tempNode.next
l1 = l1.next
l2 = l2.next
```

Just change it to the following, your code will work

```
tempNode.next = l1 
tempNode = tempNode.next
l1 = l1.next 
tempNode.next = l2
tempNode = tempNode.next
l2 = l2.next
```

Problem with your approach is that when you do `tempNode.next = l2` you're modifying the actual `ListNode` that is pointed by `l1` which make you stuck in an infinite loop

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign `l1` and `l2`'s values to `tempNode.val` instead of assigning `l1` and `l2` nodes themselves to `tempNode`'s next node. You also need to add `l1` or `l2`'s remaining values to `tempNode` if the other list is empty.

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, x=None):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None

a = ListNode(5)
b = ListNode(10)
c = ListNode(20)


e = ListNode(0)
f = ListNode(5)
g = ListNode(21)
h = ListNode(30)


a.next = b
b.next = c

e.next = f
f.next = g
g.next = h

class Solution:
    def mergeTwoLists(self, l1, l2):

        returnNode = tempNode = ListNode()

        while l1 or l2:
            if not l1:
                print('l1 is empty; adding value from l2:', l2.val)
                tempNode.val = l2.val
                tempNode.next = ListNode()
                tempNode = tempNode.next
                l2 = l2.next
            elif not l2:
                print('l2 is empty; adding value from l1:', l1.val)
                tempNode.val = l1.val
                tempNode.next = ListNode()
                tempNode = tempNode.next
                l1 = l1.next
            elif l1.val < l2.val:

                print("l1.val < l2.val", l1.val, l2.val)
                tempNode.val = l1.val

                tempNode.next = ListNode()
                tempNode = tempNode.next
                l1 = l1.next

            elif l1.val == l2.val:

                print("l1.val == l2.val", l1.val, l2.val)

                #If both the values are equal, assign l1's value first
                #then make l2's value follow l1's value using tempNode

                tempNode.val = l1.val
                tempNode.next = ListNode() #Because of the previous statement, after execution of this statement, I'm assuming tempNode.val is now l1.val and tempNode.next = l1.next
                tempNode = tempNode.next

                #tempNode.next is supposed to be equal to l1.next, instead assign it to l2
                tempNode.val = l2.val
                tempNode.next = ListNode() #Because of the previous statement, after execution of this statement, I'm assuming tempNode.val is now l2.val and tempNode.next = l2.next
                tempNode = tempNode.next

                #Increment both l1 and l2
                l1 = l1.next
                l2 = l2.next


            else:
                print("l1.val > l2.val", l1.val, l2.val)
                tempNode.val = l2.val

                tempNode.next = ListNode()
                tempNode = tempNode.next
                l2 = l2.next
        return returnNode

sol = Solution()
node = sol.mergeTwoLists(a, e)
while node and node.val is not None:
    print(node.val)
    node = node.next
```

This outputs:

```
l1.val > l2.val 5 0
l1.val == l2.val 5 5
l1.val < l2.val 10 21
l1.val < l2.val 20 21
l1 is empty; adding value from l2: 21
l1 is empty; adding value from l2: 30
0
5
5
10
20
21
30
```

Comment: Thanks @blhsing! I had to accept pulkit's answer because it concisely addressed the problem I was facing. `You also need to add l1 or l2's remaining values to  tempNode if the other list is empty.` I know I had to do this part, I purposely did not add this or ask this in the question because that would make it too lengthy. Thanks for your help, I've upvoted your answer too.

Comment: @Abhishek Did you try pulkit-singhal's code at all? It won't work. I modified a lot more than pulkit-singhal's answer to make your code work. Please examine the changes closely. The point is to assign `l1` and `l2`'s values to `tempNode`'s value, not pointers. pulkit-singhal's answer is actually incorrect. Accepting his/her answer makes no sense.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Kwz96zNk Here is the code! With his added part! It worked for the leetcode question that I'm dealing with! I had to change it the way pulkit posted it with the added change that instead of `(l1.next != None) and (l2.next != None)` in the `while` condition, I had to give it as `(l1 != None) and (l2 != None)`. The pastebin link expires in one hour.

Comment: Yes, the while condition needs fixing like I did in my solution, but also your solution would alter both `l1` and `l2`'s lists along the way of building `tempNode` since you're reusing `l1` and `l2`'s nodes directly without instantiating new ones. But if you don't care about `l1` and `l2` being altered then I guess it's okay (after fixing the while condition)

Comment: Your answer is NOT wrong by any means! But because I'm a newbie to programming that it takes me time to see the difference between `if f1:` and `if f1 == True:` and so it gives me a brain freeze for a few seconds when you say `if f1 or f2`. I don't have much programming experience. His code simply dealt with the part of the code that needed fixing. I hadn't mentioned if it mattered if `l1` or `l2` were altered and I had ALSO mentioned that for now I didn't care about the rest of the unfinished linked list. So I'm sorry I'm not picking your answer. My lack of experience is the problem here.